# Navigation to another stack bottomNavigation react-native-paper

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-native-paper

don't know how to navigate to another stack using react-native-paper and react-navigation

```
function RootStack(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          presentation: 'transparentModal',
          headerShown: false
        }}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name={'BottomStack'}
            component={BottomStack}
          />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

BottomStack with react-native-paper

```
import { BottomNavigation, Text } from 'react-native-paper'

const BottomStack = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
  const [routes] = useState([
    {
      key: 'home',
      title: 'Home',
      focusedIcon: 'home',
      unfocusedIcon: 'heart-outline'
    },
    { key: 'jobs', title: 'Jobs', focusedIcon: 'album' }
  ])

  const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
    home: HomeStack,
    jobs: JobsStack
  })

  return (
    <BottomNavigation
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      onIndexChange={setIndex}
      renderScene={renderScene}
    />
  )
}
```

HomeStack - JobsStack is similar

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

function HomeStack(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={Routes.HOME}>
        <Stack.Screen name={'Home'} component={Home} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

When I select the Jobs tab I get this error:
[image]

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an issue with React Paper's `BottomNavigation`. Didn't look deeply into it but it might have an internal `NavigationContainer` which might be causing the issue.

This article helped with nesting navigators:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#nesting-multiple-navigators

This article also mentions that it wraps the `BottomNavigation` component from `react-native-paper`:
https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/guides/bottom-navigation/

```
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const BottomNav = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Jobs" component={Jobs} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
const BottomStack = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          presentation: 'transparentModal',
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen
          name={'BottomNavigation'}
          options={{title: 'BottomNavigation'}}
          component={BottomNav}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

function Home(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={'home'}>
      <Stack.Screen name={'Home'} component={Home} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function Jobs(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={'jobs'}>
      <Stack.Screen name={'Jobs'} component={Jobs} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return <BottomStack />;
}
```

I replaced it with the Tab convention and it was able to build fine.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by following this guide: [BottomNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2020/01/29/using-react-navigation-5-with-react-native-paper/#bottom-navigation)

Comment: Can you be specific in which examples you followed? I followed this as well, but it doesn't specify how to combine stack navigation with the bottom tab.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have two nested navigators: `Stack.navigator` inside `BottomNavigation`. You must have only one top-level navigator (one main screen from which you can navigate to all the rest).
To fix this, you can move `Stack.Navigator` from `HomeStack` and `JobsStack`, all into `BottomStack`. here's how:

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

const BottomStack = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
  const [routes] = useState([
    {
      key: 'home',
      title: 'Home',
      focusedIcon: 'home',
      unfocusedIcon: 'heart-outline'
    },
    { key: 'jobs', title: 'Jobs', focusedIcon: 'album' }
  ])

  const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
    home: Home,
    jobs: Jobs
  })

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          presentation: 'transparentModal',
          headerShown: false
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen
          name={'BottomNavigation'}
          options={{ title: 'BottomNavigation' }}>
          {() => (
            <BottomNavigation
              navigationState={{ index, routes }}
              onIndexChange={setIndex}
              renderScene={renderScene}
            />
          )}
        </Stack.Screen>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

function Home(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={Routes.HOME}>
      <Stack.Screen name={'Home'} component={HomeScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

function Jobs(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={Routes.JOBS}>
      <Stack.Screen name={'Jobs'} component={JobsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Comment: Tried following this but didn't work. Still got "Another navigator is already registered for this container"